# How to add wordpress plugin in cs-cart

Tags: php

I had integrate the wordpress with the cs-cart.How to add the wordpress plugins in the cs-cart site(inside the page)?

Comment: Please, if any one know the solution for this help me..

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather there's no short answer to this question.., you might get started looking at the [API docs](http://docs.cs-cart.com/).  At the end of the day I don't think the Wordpress plugins will port directly over, there's probably some work you'll have to do for each one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... can you know how to use php codings in the tpl file?

Comment: cs-cart use smarty PHP in order to write PHP in tpl files

Comment: Very old post.. but what do you mean "I had integrate the wordpress with the cs-cart"? These are two diffenrent CMS and working in different ways.. What have you done in order to intergrate the plugins of Wordpress to CS-Cart addons? You need to add the appropriate code of wordpress to cs-cart hooks and so on.. if you need any specific help, please let me know, so I could help you